# Projective embedding of a compact complex surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact complex surface which admits a holomorphic line bundle $L$ with $c_1^2(L)>0$. Can we prove that $M$ is projective?

Comment: If $c_1^2(L)$ is positive, then by Riemann-Roch and Serre duality, either $L$ or $L^\vee$ is big.  So $M$ is at least Moishezon.  Then use "Goodman's theorem" to prove that $M$ is in fact projective.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is precisely Theorem (6.2), p. 160 of

*Barth, Wolf P.; Hulek, Klaus; Peters, Chris A. M.; Van de Ven, Antonius*, Compact complex surfaces, Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete. 3. Folge 4. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-00832-2/hbk). xii, 436 p. (2004). [ZBL1036.14016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1036.14016).

Comment: Just to comment on the difference between that proof and the one I sketched: in the proof using Goodman's theorem, we "forget" $L$ after we use it to prove that $M$ is Moishezon.  Instead, Goodman shows that the closed complement of any Zariski open that is affine supports an ample divisor.  So instead of modifying $L$ to satisfy Nakai-Moishezon or Grauert, we just use Goodman's ample divisor.